# Exponentional values in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exponential

Have a case of quite huge numbers in python pandas, so the dataframe looks like this:

```
trades
4.536115e+07
3.889124e+07
2.757327e+07
```

How can these numbers be transformed into "normal" values from exponential in pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: The numbers are stored in binary internally. The representation on screen has nothing to do with the actual numbers. Could you explain what your actual problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the pandas options as such:

```
>>> data = np.array([4.536115e+07, 3.889124e+07, 2.757327e+07])
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.f' % x)
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['trades'])

    trades
0   45361150
1   38891240
2   27573270
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> float(4.536115e+07)
45361150.0
```

or

```
>>> f = 4.536115e+07
>>> "%.16f" % f
'45361150.0000000000000000'
```